# LoadRunner replay error : Action.c(312): Error -26630: HTTP Status-Code=401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, vugen

I have co-related all the required dynamic values, added cookies & headers in the recorded load test script. But, I can't able to get a successful login into the application.

It throws an error **Action.c(312): Error -26630: HTTP Status-Code=401 (Unauthorized)** in the login transaction itself.

```
Action.c(312): Error -26630: HTTP Status-Code=401 (Unauthorized) for "https://myapplicationURL"     [MsgId: MERR-26630]
```

Is there any other missing values need to be added in the script, Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://ptfrontline.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/loadrunner-http-401-authentication/

Google query, " 401 LoadRunner Base64 header"

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you haven't correlated the the dynamic values. Or the credentials that you are using are not valid.

You can debug this problem by looking into the snapshots of your previous requests.